# VisualState, StoryBoard, Instant change of color (without animation)

Tags: c#, wpf, winrt-xaml

my task seemed to me as something easy (WinRT).

All I want is to change color of `Rectangle` depending on state.

I know how to do it in a "cool" animated way.

The thing is that I just want my color to be changed immediately without any animation.

This is a standard, cool way:

```
<VisualState x:Name="UnFocused">
    <Storyboard Duration="1">
        <ColorAnimation To="{ThemeResource LightGrayColor}"   
            Storyboard.TargetName="borderBrush"  
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"/>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

I thought that if I change `Duration` to zero then the change will be instant.

It does not work this way, color did not change at all.

So I tried "0:0:0.1" but it did not change color either.

So...

What is the current approach to change color in instant using `VisualState` functionality?

Thank you :-)

Comment: why do you need to use VisualState? can't you just use IsFocused?

Comment: No because I have more then one state.

Comment: The answer to this problem is very easy. All I had to do is setting `Duration` to zero not in a `Storyboard` but in `ColorAnimation` itself.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether WinRT has some restrictions. At least I would also have expected that zero works fine. But you have some more options and still being cool:

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:00"
                                Storyboard.TargetName="borderBrush"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color">
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{ThemeResource LightGrayColor}"/>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

or

```
<ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="borderBrush"
                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color">
    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" 
                         Value="{ThemeResource LightGrayColor}" />
</ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

Comment: Why use animations if the control/object is not going to be animated? it's unnecessary and will cause additional overhead

Comment: d.moncada- could you please suggest some solution?

Comment: I need to look into it, but you don't want to use animation behavior if there is not going to be animation. animations are also notorious for memory leaks

Answer (score 0):

Turning @Jacek-Wojcik's comment into an answer:

Don't set a duration on the storyboard, set it on the ColorAnimation instead:

```
<VisualState x:Name="UnFocused">
  <Storyboard >
    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="{ThemeResource LightGrayColor}"   
        Storyboard.TargetName="borderBrush"  
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"/>
 </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```